# Cent OS 6.3: How to make places show up folders in tabbed versions (or at least not in a new window)

Tags: centos

I moved to CentOS 6.3 recently. The places application shows folders but each folder is shown in a new window. So if I go to 2 different folders and go deep in 3 sub folders, I will have six windows open. I thne end up closing all the folders and it becomes a problem. Is there  a way to open folders in tab

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121818/how-do-i-set-nautilus-to-use-same-window-on-double-click

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to this. So I have started using Konqueror. Places on Ubuntu 11.04 + seems to have these features but not on CentOS 6.3